# How to know how many api calls are being made to Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i want to sort how many api calls are being made to my mongodb, I want to log them in a file and then count them with wc -l, do you know how to do that?, or do you have any other suggestion?
thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "API calls"? Is this for your own API, or are you referring to MongoDB op counters (inserts, updates, queries, deletes, commands, ...)?

Comment: I mean an api call from an external service, I dont want the mongo queries and internal stuff, I want to know the number of api calls made by the external service

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you are after the following command

```
db.serverStatus()
```

the [Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/server-status/) show what the output is like 
you could output this to file if you want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some client/abstraction layer between api calls and your DB, you could maintain a separate collection to store API usage data.

Create a document for every resource with the name of that resource, and increment (`$inc`) a counter every time they are called. You could add any other extraneous data as well.